# Ask confirmation after link is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following link on my HTML:

```
<a href="/posts/1/delete" class="delete">Delete</a>
```

And I have the click event:

```
$("a.delete").on("click", function (event) {
  // Delete post
}
```

However, before the post is deleted I need to ask the user to confirm.

So I need to add the following to the HTML:

```
<div class="message">Are you sure? Yes Button / No Button</div>
```

The procedure should be something like:

```
message.delay(400).slideDown(0.9)
// Ask question
message.slideUp(400, function () { $(this).remove(); });
// At the end the message DIV should be removed
```

I would like to have this as a plugin to be reusable. For example:

```
<a href="/posts/1/delete" class="delete confirm" data-question="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: where is the link element relative to `message` element? Are there more than one message class? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure about your question but when the Link is clicked it should add the message DIV to the HTML and show it ... The message DIV does not exist before the link is clicked.

Comment: Can `confirm` be used?

Comment: Create a demo. What happens when user accepts also? too many unknowns here

Comment: If user accepts then the message slides down and the code event inside the Click event runs. Basically it calls a URL using Ajax.

Comment: Ok and is there only one message element or is there one for each delete element? What you are asking is not complicated...but you haven't really provided a well structured question for it

Comment: Listen on the click events and use callbacks. Don't expect others to write all of your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.message = function (options) {
    $(this).each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      $this.on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var cnfrm = $("<div class='cnfrm'>" + $this.attr("data-question") + "<button class='y'>Yes</button><button class='n'>No</button>");
        $this.after(cnfrm);

        cnfrm.find(".y").on("click", function() {
            $this.slideUp(400, function () { 
                $(this).remove();
                location.href = $this.attr("href");
            });
        });
      });
    });
    return this;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Not quite I understand ... I need to add the message DIV to the HTML when the A tag is clicked, slide down, ask the question and slide up only after confirmation. An in that case the code associated with the link click is followed

Comment: I just updated my question to clarify what I am looking for